# Donate button option

Tags: paypal-buttons

We already have a Donate button on our site. Now we want that button to bring up 2 choices of which fund the donation will go to. GENERAL FUND or BUILDING FUND. Is this possible and if so, how? We're not programmers.

Comment: if paypal allows it you can, otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

Not being programmers makes this a bit trickier. While David's answer is technically correct in that paypal doesn't support this, there might be an easier alternative if you're willing to change your definition of success.

The paypal button maker allows you to choose your own image for the button. Therefore, you can make two buttons, one that says General Fund and another that says Building Fund.

It won't be a single button that brings up two options, but it's close and more importantly, is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one account for both funds and just want to know in each transaction which fund the money should go to, then you can add a drop down option. You can do this inside your paypal account where you create buttons.

If you have two separate accounts for each fund, you will need two different donation buttons for each fund.